# Example of a homomorphism with a right or left inverse function that its right or left inverse is not a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

If $f: A \to B$ is an injective or surjective homomorphism, then $f$ has a left or right inverse map respectively. The question is whether the right or left inverse function of $f$ is itself a homomorphism. I'm looking for examples that this doesn't happen.

Comment: what kind of objects are $A,B$?

Comment: @AdamHughes: Well, I have R-modules in my mind, but does it matter? I mean are there categories that a surjective/injective morphism has a right/left inverse map which is also a morphism in that category?

Comment: Well, if you want to talk about right/left inverses then they need to be functions, i.e. defined on small categories where the objects are sets. So without that information, the context matters.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Yes, you're right. Thanks. I have concrete categories in mind. Like R-modules and R-homomorphisms between them.

Comment: Take the surjective homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/(n)$, $n\ne0$.

Comment: Please note that left and right inverses are not unique in general. So you should not ask about **the** left/right inverse, but about **a** left/right inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy, let's just do it for some $\Bbb Z$-modules, i.e. abelian groups.

Let $A=\Bbb Z/2$ and $B=V=\Bbb Z/2\oplus \Bbb Z/2$ be the Klein 4-group.

Let $f(1)=(1,1)$. Then a left-inverse for $f$ is given by

$$\begin{cases}f_L:B\to A \\ (0,0),(1,0),(0, 1)\mapsto 0 \\ (1,1)\mapsto 1\end{cases}$$

clearly this cannot be a group homomorphism since we send a generating set to $0$, but the map is not the trivial map. It is also clearly a left-inverse for $f$.

For a surjective morphism, $f:A\to B$ we seek a right-inverse which is not a morhpism. This is really easy, though. We now let $A=V$ and $B=\Bbb Z/2$. Let

$$\begin{cases}f: A\to B \\ (1,1), (1,0)\mapsto 1 \\ (0,0),(0,1)\mapsto 0\end{cases}$$

Then a right inverse is

$$\begin{cases}f_R: B\to A \\ 0\mapsto (0,1) \\ 1\mapsto (1,1)\mapsto 1\end{cases}$$

The compositum is the identity on $B$, verifying the condition, but clearly the chosen inverse is not a homomorphism.